# How to change the MS Charts label font size in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, charts, label, mschart

I have created few MS charts. Below code extracted from my application. It is working fine. but I want to increase the font size of label. How can I change the font size of label ?

Thanks.

```
 Series MIN = Chart2.Series.Add("Minimum");
 MIN.Points.DataBindXY(listVersion, MIN_list[j]);
 MIN.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
 MIN.Color = Color.Red;
 MIN.BorderWidth = 3;
 MIN.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
 MIN.LabelBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
 MIN.LabelForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `Font` individually for each `DataPoint`:

```
MIN.Points[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 10f);
MIN.Points[1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 12f);
MIN.Points[2].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 14f);
```

Or you can change the `Font` for **all** `Labels` of your series:

```
MIN.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times", 16f);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
   Chart2.ChartAreas.["yourChartArea"].AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None;

   Chart2.ChartAreas.["yourChartArea"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font 
= new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 2.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: It changes the label in X-Axis. Actually I want to change the label on graphs. Please refer this [image] (http://oi67.tinypic.com/vyxe29.jpg)